# Delete data using modal box in laravel

Tags: laravel, controller, routes, modal-dialog

I have some problem to delete data with confirmation (in this case using modal box) in laravel.

This is my delete button

```html
{{ Form::open(array(
                                'route' => array('delete_spk', $spk_data->id),
                                'method' => 'put',
                                'style' => 'display:inline'
                                ))
                            }}
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-line btn-rect" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delSpk" data-title="Delete SPK" data-message='Are you sure you want to delete this data ?'>
                            <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete</button>
                            {{ Form::close() }}
```

This is the modal box

```html
<!--MODAL DELETE SPK-->
<div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="modal fade" id="delSpk" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="H4"> Delete SPK</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                        <p class="help-block">Are you sure you want to delete this data ?</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-line btn-rect" id="confirm">Yes</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-line btn-rect" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<!--END OF MODAL DELETE SPK-->

<!-- Dialog show event handler -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#delSpk').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $message = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-message');
      $(this).find('.modal-body p').text($message);
      $title = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-title');
      $(this).find('.modal-title').text($title);

      // Pass form reference to modal for submission on yes/ok
      var form = $(e.relatedTarget).closest('form');
      $(this).find('.modal-footer #confirm').data('form', form);
  });

  <!-- Form confirm (yes/ok) handler, submits form -->
  $('#delSpk').find('.modal-footer #confirm').on('click', function(){
      $(this).data('form').submit();
  });
</script>
```

This is the route

```html
Route::get('spk/destroy/{id}', array('as'=>'delete_spk','uses'=>'SpkController@destroy'));
```

And this is the Controller for delete the data

```html
public function destroy()
 {
  $spk= Spk::find(Input::get('id'))->delete();
        Session::flash('message', 'Successfully deleted the SPK !');
        return Redirect::to('spk_view');
 }
```

The modal box is working, but when I'm getting the ID to delete, this will be ended with results "method not allowed http exception". Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happens because you have defined the route as GET but submitting the form as PUT

If you define you route as below then it must work

```
Route::put('spk/destroy/{id}', array('as'=>'delete_spk','uses'=>'SpkController@destroy'));
```